# HERE API autocomplete does not return Mexico City

Tags: autocomplete, here-api, here-maps-rest

HERE API autocomplete does not return Mexico City with the following request:

[https://autocomplete.search.hereapi.com/v1/autocomplete?q=mexico&apikey=[myApiKey]&lang=en-US&types=city](https://autocomplete.search.hereapi.com/v1/autocomplete?q=mexico&apikey=%5BmyApiKey%5D&lang=en-US&types=city)

It worked fine with the old API. Is there something wrong with my query or should I use other endpoint for searching Mexico or Mexico City in order to get the Mexico City town?

Answer (score 0):

At this moment new GS7 HERE API doesn't completely covered Mexico country opposite to HERE Geocoder 6.2.

For 6.2 see please on https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/coverage-geocoder.html

> full: premium house no., street level

For GS7 see please on https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/search-local-coverage.html

> Entry-level search experience